# The Order Of Zero Of $1-\cos(z-1)$ at $z_0=1$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Find the order $f$ zero of $1-\cos(z-1)$ at $z_0=1$

One way will be to look at the Taylor expansion $\displaystyle 1-\cos(z-1)=1-(1+\frac{(z-1)^2}{2!} - \frac{(z-1)^4}{4!}+\cdots)$ and to see that the  $z_0=1$ is a a root of the second element of the Taylor expansion

($1$ is the $0th$, element $0\cdot z$ is the first and $\displaystyle \frac{(z-1)^2}{2!}$ is the $2$ element?)

Or we can look for the first derivative $z_0=0$ is a root of it.

So in $\cos(z-1)$ that is the second derivative

Is that correct?

Comment: Last time I checked, we had $\cos(0) = 1$. And your power series isn't quite right, either. At any rate, to talk about order of zero of an analytic function $f$ at $z=a$, you'd better have $f(a)=0$. If $f(a)\ne 0$, it's a zero of order $0$, I guess, but no one really talks about that.

Comment: Sorry forgot 1 before the $cosz$

Comment: And correcting the question, title included, would kill you?

Comment: @Did 100% I fixed the question on the bus, forgotten the title

Answer (score 1):

A complex number $a$ is zero of analytic function $f$, if $f(a)=0$.

Here, at $z_0=1$, $cos(z-1)_{z_0=1} = cos(0) = 1$. This implies, $z_0=1$ is not the zero of $cos(z-1)$.

Here, $f(z) = 1 - cos(z-1)$.

By Taylor,
$1 - cos(z-1) = (z-1)^2 g(z)$, where $g(z) = - (\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{(z-1)^2}{4!}+\cdots)$ such that $g(1) \neq 0$. So, order of $f(z)$ at $z=1$ is 2.

OR, calculate $f'(z) = sin(z-1)$ and $f''(z) = cos(z-1)$. So, $f(1)=0$ and $f'(1)=0$. But, $f''(1)\neq 0$. So, order is $2$ again.

Comment: Sorry forgot 1 before the $cosz$